# Purging GNOME from system?

Tags: apt, gnome

I am trying to remove any part of `GNOME` from my system, and replace it with a different desktop environment. The problem is that I have no idea how to do that.

My idea was to run `sudo apt-get purge gnome-*`, but that seems to remove a HUGE amount of programs including `blueman` and `network-manager` which I'd like to keep.

Is it possible to remove everything gnome from my system, without removing the useful plugins that shouldn't be related to `GNOME` such as `tlp`, `update-manager` and so on?

NOTE: I installed `Ubuntu Mate`, so `gnome` isn't even the DE the system came packaged with. But `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` doesn't even exist.

Comment: Please ensure you back-up your valuable data first because there's a strong chance you'll end up with a broken system. You're better off doing a clean install of a distro that actually has the desktop environment you want in the first place.

Comment: I guess you're right. It was easy to uninstall MATE after months of using but it seems like GNOME is the infectious plague of desktop environments

Comment: Please mention all the DE’s you have installed and your Ubuntu version. _“I installed Ubuntu Mate, so gnome isn't even the DE the system came packaged with”_ MATE is based on GNOME (or at least Gtk+).

Comment: I have GNOME, and i3, which is a window manager. I uninstalled MATE though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace GNOME with much more lightweight [i3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i3), it is expectable that many GUI applications depending on GNOME would be uninstalled due to dependencies, too.

Regarding your examples:

- [`blueman`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/blueman) depends on `gnome-icon-theme`
- [`network-manager`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/network-manager) [recommends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77053/54675) `network-manager-gnome`

If you want to keep them, you will need to keep required parts of GNOME. And as mentioned in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038692/purging-gnome-from-system#comment1691228_1038692), **be sure to have a backup** before <strike>trying to break</strike> doing such a serious modification to your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I ended up formatting the whole thing and just dumping Kubuntu on it. Backups are perfect though!